# Update Java used by Mathematica 10

Tags: version-10, java

I would like to update the Java version used by Mathmematica 10 from 1.7.x to 1.8.x/ Is it possible without installing Mathematica 11?

I have the latest Java on my system, but Mathematica 10 uses an old one.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`ReinstallJava`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/ReinstallJava.html) with the `CommandLine` option.

```
ReinstallJava[CommandLine->"d:\\full\\path\\to\\java.exe"]
```

This information is not on `ReinstallJava`'s documentation page but in the [Calling Java from the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromTheWolframLanguage.html) guide under the *Launching the Java Runtime | Controlling the Command Used to Launch Java* section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already tried this, and I didn't work. But I will try it again, thanks!

Comment: @pnz Try calling [`UninstallJava`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/UninstallJava.html) first.  That might help.